# Configure User Profile Service with Business Data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, 2016

We have a SQL Server view which contains users Samaccountname, phone number, id, picture, department and title
We will like to configure User Profile Service with information from that view instead of connecting to AD directly for two reasons : 1. SHarePoint Service Account does not have sufficients access to AD, and 2. Pictures are not stored in AD but are stored in HR DataBase, so that view have information from HR and AD.
Microsoft says that it possible to connect User Profile Service to Business Data, but i can't find any documentation about that.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BDC is only supported for *appending* data to a User Profile. It cannot *create* a user profile. There are various reasons for this, but one key piece of information you would be missing in your database is the user's SID, which is required for AD-based objects.

[HOW TO: Create UserProfile Synchronization connection to BCS and map User Profile Property to BCS field in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2013/03/18/how-to-create-userprofile-synchronization-connection-to-bcs-and-map-user-profile-property-to-bcs-field-in-sharepoint-2010/)